# Should I publish a new library version when making non functional changes?

Tags: javascript, npm

I'm maintaining a set of javascript libraries and it's usual to have to update some dependencies that doesn't require any functional changes for instance when my library is not affected by a dependency breaking change.

Do you usually publish a new version of the library once updated its dependencies or wait to have to make a functional change for publishing a new version?

Also, do you include which dependencies have been update in the changelog?

PD: I'm using semantic versioning

Comment: I would recommend it to release it with a minor update when you are using sem. versioning. The thing is you cant now if maybe the update breaks something for people even if its not in your library. So its just a nice gesture to inform everyone involved and let them know what has changed.

Comment: I should have said that I'm using sem. versioning yes

Comment: Then you have to decide now if its a `minor` or `patch`.
You can check [semver.org](https://semver.org/) for detailed explanations when to apply which version strategy/number. See my answer.

Comment: Updating your dependency declarations to work with newer versions might be important for those users who need to update those libraries and need to have your library be compatible. So yes, release immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using [`semver`](https://semver.org/) you would have to release a `minor` update.

From the docs:

> Patch version Z (x.y.Z | x > 0) MUST be incremented if only backwards compatible bug fixes are introduced. A bug fix is defined as an internal change that fixes incorrect behavior.
>
> Minor version Y (x.Y.z | x > 0) **MUST be incremented if new, backwards compatible functionality is introduced to the public API**. It MUST be incremented if any public API functionality is marked as deprecated. **It MAY be incremented if substantial new functionality or improvements are introduced within the private code.** It MAY include patch level changes. Patch version MUST be reset to 0 when minor version is incremented.

So I would suggest to also take the updates of the 3rd party libraries into consideration and decide depending on what features they have introduced and decide based on this.

You have to take into consideration that depending on what distribution channels are used (and they may change) developers might have extended your library to a way that they are also using features of third partys which your library depends on or themselves depend on.

In the end there is not THE RULE but in my opinion more information is better than no information because you dont know what other developers try to accomplish.

Comment: I haven't tick your response yet because I think there is still something that worth clarifying, first off thanks for pointing me to semver because I took the time to read it carefully.

Comment: @BorjaTur Why dont you tell me what it is?

Comment: I think the point to consider if that whatever you are changing does affect to the public interface of your lib or not, if the public API is affected somehow then is a must publishing but if is only affecting to the private part of your lib (e.g. code refactor, dependency that is not affecting anything in the public interface) then semver only says "It MAY be incremented" so is up to the maintainer whether publishing or not

Comment: That said, I fully agree with you and I think is generally good practice uplifting your versions always a change is introduced and having a detailed changelog that reflects it regardless changes are affecting either public or private interface.

Comment: so if you agree and if you don't mind updating your response I'll tick it as the preferred one